# What is material is the HTC Nexus One Screen made out of?

Tags: nexus-one, screen

Some say it is plastic, others insist it's glass. Wikipedia provides shady information.

Answer (score 5):

The screen is glass. Since the release people were having issues with the screen due to the glass sometimes cracking when in tight pockets... this would usually not occur with plastic since plastic is a little bit more flexible.

1. [HTC says broken glass means Nexus One not for pocket](http://www.androidarena.com/2010/03/09/htc-says-broken-glass-means-nexus-one-not-for-pocket/)
2. [Design: Solid, but Not Groundbreaking](http://www.pcworld.com/reviews/product/374818/review/nexus_one.html)